# Is it possible to get the first attack against Warbear foot soldiers?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I've tried equipping all the +initiative equipment I've had, while running with springy fusilli, soul rotation, and an oily boid as a familiar, and I've still had no success with first striking to minimize damage.

Is it possible to act first? I'd like to know before burning useful consumables in a hardcore run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one way you can't, in another, you always do.

Warbear Foot Soldiers have a ludicrously low initiative (even with -100% I acted first) but they also have a passive ability that damages you before the fight starts. This can be seen by the lack of overlap between the messages on warbear attacks, and the initial supercold damage; but is made less obvious by the fact that warbears deal supercold damage.

This means that the warbears cannot be defeated without taking at least some damage, but appropriate equipment and familiars can help you regenerate more than you lose.